# Layout broken when viewDidDisappear

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I Wear several days trying to solve the following problem but I have not gotten anything :(

[image]

I have a viewController with a UIScrollView and some subViews, I'm adding some of them by interface builder and others by code. When I call the method for push the next viewController, the current view breaks and still broken when I pop it.

I've tried to remove Autolayout setting from Storyboard but still not working.

I'm setting the frames of the views programmatically and I move the content offset of the scrollView for make the animation.

I'm calling this method in viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)prepareQuestion
{
    int nextYposition;

    // Question
    NSString *q = [self.theQuestion getQuestionTextForLanguage:lang];
    NSString *badText = [self.theQuestion getInfTextForLanguage:lang];
    NSString *goodText = [self.theQuestion getSupTextForLanguage:lang];

    self.answer.questionID = self.theQuestion.questionID;

    if (whiteStyle) {
        question = [[NPSQuestionViewController alloc] initWithQuestion:q AndStyle:kNPSQuestionStyleWhite];
    } else {
        question = [[NPSQuestionViewController alloc] initWithQuestion:q AndStyle:kNPSQuestionStyleOther];
    }

    question.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - 50);
    [self addChildViewController:question];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:question.view];

    nextYposition = question.view.frame.origin.y + question.view.frame.size.height;

    int questionHeight = 0; // Guardamos el alto dependiendo del tipo de control

    if (self.sliderStyle) {
        // Slider test
        if (whiteStyle) {
            NPSSliderViewControl = [[NPSSliderViewController alloc] initWithStyle:kNPSSliderViewStyleWhite];
        } else {
            NPSSliderViewControl = [[NPSSliderViewController alloc] initWithStyle:kNPSSliderViewStyleOther];
        }

        NPSSliderViewControl.iconSet = [[[OpinatManager sharedInstance] campanya] tipoIconos];
        [NPSSliderViewControl setBadText:badText andGoodText:goodText];
        [self addChildViewController:NPSSliderViewControl];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:NPSSliderViewControl.view];
        NPSSliderViewControl.delegate = self;

        CGRect frame = NPSSliderViewControl.view.frame;
        [NPSSliderViewControl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, nextYposition, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        questionHeight = frame.size.height - 33; // 33 es el valor de la parte que desaparece del control

    } else {
        // Control
        if (whiteStyle) {
            NPSBtnViewControl = [[NPSBtnViewController alloc] initWithStyle:kNPSBtnViewStyleWhite];
        } else {
             NPSBtnViewControl = [[NPSBtnViewController alloc] initWithStyle:kNPSBtnViewStyleOther];
        }

        NPSBtnViewControl.iconSet = [[[OpinatManager sharedInstance] campanya] tipoIconos];
        [NPSBtnViewControl setBadText:badText andGoodText:goodText];
        [self addChildViewController:NPSBtnViewControl];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:NPSBtnViewControl.view];
        NPSBtnViewControl.delegate = self;

        CGRect frame = NPSBtnViewControl.view.frame;
        [NPSBtnViewControl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, nextYposition, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        questionHeight = frame.size.height - 58; // 60 es el valor de la parte que desaparece del control
    }

    nextYposition += questionHeight;

    // Motives question
    if (whiteStyle) {
        motivesQuestion = [[NPSQuestionViewController alloc] initWithQuestion:self.insatisfactionTitle AndStyle:kNPSQuestionStyleWhite];
    } else {
        motivesQuestion = [[NPSQuestionViewController alloc] initWithQuestion:self.insatisfactionTitle AndStyle:kNPSQuestionStyleOther];
    }

    CGRect secondQuestionFrame = motivesQuestion.view.frame;
    secondQuestionFrame.origin.y = nextYposition;
    motivesQuestion.view.frame = secondQuestionFrame;
    motivesQuestion.view.alpha = 0;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:motivesQuestion.view];
    motivesQuestion.view.tag = 22;

    questionHeight = motivesQuestion.view.frame.size.height;

    nextYposition += questionHeight;

    // Setting up table Y position. Only works if I setted in viewDidAppear
    nextPosition = nextYposition;
    resetPosition = nextYposition;

    // Ajustamos la tableView
    self.tableMotives.alpha = 0;
}
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Show your code for setting frames. You should be modifying constraint offsets...

Comment: post your code what you did tried

Comment: @Wain, iDev I put it, thanks.

Comment: BTW--I would only do layout in my view's `-layoutSubviews` code, not in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thanks @nielsbot, I've tried but viewDidLayoutSubViews is always executed 2 times. It's correct?

Comment: What I mean is split your code into 2 parts. 1) Create new subviews programmatically in `-viewDidLoad`, then for views that require custom layout, subclass UIView and override `-layoutSubviews`. Sorry--I didn't fully specify. I _wasn't_ referring to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using auto-layout you should basically never be setting the view frames directly. Instead, you should be setting up your constraints so that everything is automatically placed in the correct place and using an `@property` to hold 'special' references to selected constraints. These 'special' constraints are ones that control the overall position of other content on the screen and they work by having a [`constant` offset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/constant).

When you want to perform some animation to change where everything is on the screen, use a `UIView` animation block and modify only the `constant`s on your constraints.

If you want to reset, again modify the `constant`s on your constraints.

Comment: Thanks Wain, I've tried to disable auto layout but the problem persists

Comment: Are you resetting all frames in `viewWillAppear:` (everything that is moved when an answer is entered)?

Comment: I'm setting all in viewWillAppear: but only the first time, when come back from the transition this code not be executed.

Comment: I'm setting all the elements in viewWillAppear: (the frames, styles and more) then I set the flag "firsTime" to NO. When I come back from the transition, this code not be executed. Sorry if I can not explain better.

Comment: Why? That means that things don't get reset when you come back. Or at least partly. It isn't clear what you want to happen, but you need to find out what is or isn't changed and shouldn't or should be...

Comment: In the first view the user interacts and it's affecting the UI. When   I call the transition, if the user wants to go back, I need that the view still with the previous UI changes.

Comment: so put a breakpoint on every line which changes a frame and see what is called during the transition to and back from it

Comment: I've deactivate again the Autolayout and I see the problem. Previously, when I push the transition, the UIScrollview contentOffset was reseted to 0 (it happens with autolayout and whitout). For this reason I thought that disabling autolayout are not working. Now, whit autolayout disabled and changing the animation target from UIScrollview.contentOffset to UIScrollview.frame.origin.y works fine! Thanks